# Can't connect to select websites

Tags: websites

I'm using Kubuntu 22.04, freshly installed on my Asus laptop. Previously Kubuntu 20.04.
For some time I had problem connecting to select websites such as youtube and github. I thought fresh install might solve it, but it didn't. Doesn't matter which browser (Firefox / Chrome / Opera). Also happends in different networks.
Can anyone help me identify the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "connecting to select websites"?

Comment: Unable to connect

An error occurred during a connection to www.youtube.com.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

Comment: Is it with all sites, or some sites, like with IPV6 capability?

Comment: It is not related to Ubuntu. It is about providers you are using and their settings.

Comment: it is specific website, currently youtube, github and aliexpress. I have no idea how IPV6 works and why is it relevant.<br/>
Other computers on the same networks use these websites perfectly fine, while my computer can't connect on any network. so it is isolated to my laptop, has to be sommething internal.

Comment: These sites have ipv6. It should work with Ubuntu without any problems. But it depends on how your local router is set up for ipv6. You can totally disable ipv6 in ubuntu, then the problem should go away.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't connect to web sites that have IPv6 addresses.

There maybe many reasons for that outside of Ubuntu.

The easiest way is to disable IPv6 addressing in Ubuntu Network Manager.

Click Networking icon on top of you screen and edit the network connection you are using. Then go to IPv6 tab and disable it there. Reconnect to the network, and the problem should be gone.